# Drupal 8 Commerce 2 Trigger custom mail to product author

Tags: 8, commerce

We can get the `uid` for purchased product after checkout using [Event Subscriber](https://medium.com/@sumanthkumarc/writing-event-subscriber-for-order-complete-event-in-drupal-8-commerce-2-x-196292330b1c).

How to sent mail to product author with product details when someone checkout the product. We can get all the details in `$order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [described in the Commerce 2 documentation](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/react-to-workflow-transitions):

> In our case we want to send the email after the transition to the
>   Fulfillment state has occurred. We therefore need to create an event
>   subscriber that listens to the commerce_order.fulfill.post_transition
>   event.

```
// my_module/src/EventSubscriber/OrderFulfillmentSubscriber.php

    namespace Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber;

    use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
    use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

    /**
     * Sends an email when the order transitions to Fulfillment.
     */
    class OrderFulfillmentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

      use StringTranslationTrait;

      /**
       * The language manager.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
       */
      protected $languageManager;

      /**
       * The mail manager.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface
       */
      protected $mailManager;

      /**
       * Constructs a new OrderFulfillmentSubscriber object.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager
       *   The language manager.
       * @param \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
       *   The mail manager.
       */
      public function __construct(
        LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager,
        MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
      ) {
        $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
        $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
      }

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events = [
          'commerce_order.fulfill.post_transition' => ['sendEmail', -100],
        ];
        return $events;
      }

      /**
       * Sends the email.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event
       *   The transition event.
       */
      public function sendEmail(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
        // Create the email.
        $order = $event->getEntity();
        $to = $order->getEmail();
        $params = [
          'from' => $order->getStore()->getEmail(),
          'subject' => $this->t(
            'Regarding your order [#@number]',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          ),
          'body' => $this->t(
            'Your order with #@number that you have placed with us has been processed and is awaiting fulfillment.',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          ),
        ];

        // Set the language that will be used in translations.
        if ($customer = $order->getCustomer()) {
          $langcode = $customer->getPreferredLangcode();
        }
        else {
          $langcode = $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
        }

        // Send the email.
        $this->mailManager->mail('commerce_order', 'receipt', $to, $langcode, $params);
      }

    }
```

Comment: How can i get the product author email. Required to sent mail to 'product author'.

Comment: @shanz This is not a code writing service.  The product is an entity so you can do a basic google search for "get entity author drupal 8".

Comment: Got the product author email using - $owner = $product->getOwner();  $ownerEmail = $owner->getEmail(); Thanks!